# Cannot set property value of null on onchange

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display the flight details of a flight depending on the flight number selected. I'm displaying a dropdown menu that displays all the flight numbers and a table that displays the details of all the flights such as terminal number, airline and date. When a flight number is selected, it should only display the details for that flight number using onchange. I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at getAjaxData (liveArrivalsNode.js: 35)
    at init (liveArrivalsNode.js: 10)
    at window.onload (liveArrivalsNode.js: 5)".

I'm not sure if my if else statement is correct. How do I get this working? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

liveArrivalsNode.js

```
var xmlhttp;

window.onload=function(){
    init();
}

function init(){            
    getAjaxData();
    getJsonData();
    setInterval(getAjaxData, 5000);

    document.getElementById("flights").onchange=function(){
        getAjaxData();
    }
}

function getAjaxData() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        showAjaxData();
    };

    var myFlight = document.getElementById("flightDDown").value;

    if(myFlight == 'All')
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/",true);
    else if(myFlight == null)
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/",true);
    else
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/flights/"+myFlight,true);

  xmlhttp.send();
}

function showAjaxData()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {       
         var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

         var output ="<table border=1>";
        output += "<tr><th></th><th>Origin</th><th>Airline</th><th>Flight</th><th>Scheduled Date</th><th>Scheduled Time</th><th>Status</th>";
        for(var i=0;i<data.arrivals.length;i++)
        {
            var terminal;
            if(data.arrivals[i].terminal == "t1")
                terminal = "<img src='images/t1.jpg'/>";
            else
                terminal = "<img src='images/t2.jpg'/>";

            output += '<tr>';
            if(data.arrivals[i].highlight == 'on')
                output += "<tr class='highlight'>";
            else
                output += "<tr class='normal'>";

            output += '<td>'+terminal+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].origin+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].airline+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].flight+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].scheduledDate+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].scheduledTime+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].status+ '<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'highlight\' value=\'data.arrivals[i].highlight\'></td></tr>';
        }
        output+="</table>";

        // add output to "fixtures" div
        document.getElementById("myFlights").innerHTML=output;
    }
}



function getJsonData() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttpSecond=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttpSecond=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttpSecond.onreadystatechange=function (){
        showJsonData();
};

// var myFlight = document.getElementById("flights").value;
xmlhttpSecond.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/flights",true);

xmlhttpSecond.send();
}

function showJsonData()
{
    if (xmlhttpSecond.readyState==4 && xmlhttpSecond.status==200)
    {       
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttpSecond.responseText);

        // var today = date('Y-m-d');
        // today = today.getFullYear() +"-"+(today.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+today.getDay();
       var flightDetails = "<form method='GET' action='index.js'>";
        flightDetails += "Filter by Flight No.: " 
        flightDetails += "<select id='flightDDown' name='flight'>";
        flightDetails += "<option value='All'>Any</option>";
        for(var i=0;i<data.flights.length;i++) 
        {
            flightDetails += "<option value="+data.flights[i].flight+">"+data.flights[i].flight+"</option>";
        }
        flightDetails+="</select></form>";

        // add output to "fixtures" div
        document.getElementById("flightDropdown").innerHTML=flightDetails;
    }
}
```

liveArrivalsNode.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colour.css">
    <script src="liveArrivalsNode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
require 'airportArrivals.html';
?>
<div id="flightDropdown"></div>

<div id="myFlights"></div>
</body>
<footer>
<caption align="bottom"><hr/><center>L00091898
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't it tell you the line in which the error occurs? Do you get the error at beginning or only when you select something? How does your HTML-look like at the beginning?

Comment: Wouldn't the problem be that you are trying to read the value of `flightDDown` element without checking that the element exists at that time? From your workflow, it seems that `init()` gets called first, then `getAjaxData()` and this one tries to read the value of the `flightDDown` combobox that you only seem to create once you get to the `showAjaxData()`

Comment: I think the problem is that this call `document.getElementById("flightDDown")` is executed before the `showJsonData()` function (before the element with id `flightDDown`is added to the document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to read a property from an object with the value `null`.

From the workflow it seems that this is caused by trying to read the value of a non existing element in your `getAjaxData()` function. Where you read the value you could change it to the following

```
var myFlight = document.getElementById("flightDDown");
```

and simultaniously change the if statement, to first check if it's null or if it's selected value equals `'All'` (if it's null, it won't check the selected value and since you are using the same url, it shouldn't be a problem)

```
if(myFlight == null || myFlight.value === 'All')
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/",true);
else
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/flights/"+myFlight.value,true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now getting an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null  at init (liveArrivalsNode.js: 12)  at window.onload (liveArrivalsNode.js: 5)". Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: @GleneaMan same principle, you are trying to get an element that doesn't exist yet, an then try to bind an eventhandler to the `onchange` method of an object evaluating to `null`